# Quais as diferenças entre Contêiner(Docker), Serviço de aplicativo(App service) e Service Fabric no Azure?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, docker, microsserviços, microsoft-azure

Quando vamos publicar uma aplicação, serviço ou Web API temos hoje uma grande diversidade de opções. Eu particularmente gosto do Azure pela sua mentalidade de facilitar as configurações pelo painel e passando a complexidade para outras partes da aplicação(quando possível).

Sob esse aspecto, fiquei com algumas dúvidas quanto as opções mais recentes oferecidas pelo Azure. Nas documentações do Azure me parece que vários serviços podem atender a mesma necessidade.

Quais as diferenças entre publicar uma aplicação, serviço ou Web API nas seguintes ferramentas?

- Azure Contêiner service
- Azure Service Fabric
- Azure Serviço de aplicativo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de você conseguir alguns resultados idênticos com as 3 opções, é necessário avaliar o cenário que mais se encaixa no seu problema, uma vez que não faz muito sentido subir um site simples com Contêiner ou Service Fabric.

### Azure Contêiner Service

O Azure Container Service facilita a criação, configuração e gerenciamento de um cluster de máquinas virtuais pré-configuradas para executar aplicativos em contêiner. Ele usa uma configuração otimizada de populares ferramentas de programação e orquestração de código aberto. Isso permite que você use suas habilidades existentes ou aproveite um grande e crescente corpo de experiência da comunidade para implantar e gerenciar aplicativos baseados em contêiner no Microsoft Azure. Um dos bons motivos para se utilizar Contêiner é:

- Ambientes parecidos
- Aplicação como pacote completo
- Padronização e replicação
- Você precisa de uma infraestrutura que pode ser escalada para cima ou para baixo com base nas necessidades de cada aplicação.
- Você precisa de implantações rápidas em todos os seus ambientes.
- Garantir que não falte qualquer dependência da sua aplicação, pois já está tudo dentro do contêiner.
- Se você tem experiência com algumas soluções de orquestração como Docker, Swarm, Google Kubernetes.

**Segue alguns links para entender melhor como funciona o Azure Conteiner Service**

- http://www.e-seth.com.br/tecnapratica/index.php/2016/12/13/azure-container-service-introducao/
- http://techfree.com.br/2016/03/porque-usar-docker/

### Azure Service Fabric

O Azure Service Fabric é uma plataforma de sistemas distribuídos que facilita o empacotamento, implantação e gerenciamento de microsserviços e contêineres escalonáveis e confiáveis. Desenvolvedores e administradores podem evitar problemas complexos de infraestrutura e se concentrarem na implementação de cargas de trabalho essenciais e exigentes que são escalonáveis, confiáveis e gerenciáveis. Um dos bons motivos para se usar o Azure Service Fabric:

- Quando precisamos de serviços de grande escala
- Quando precisamos de serviços altamente disponíveis
- Quando precisamos de serviços facilmente escalonável
- Quando precisamos de serviços interativos baseados em sessão
- Quando precisamos de serviços com alto fluxo de análise de dados
- Quando precisamos de serviços para coleta de dados e processamento IoT
- Quando precisamos implantar serviços de forma simples tanto na nuvem quanto local (OnPremise).

**Segue alguns links para entender melhor como funciona o Azure Service Fabric**

- https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/service-fabric/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/service-fabric/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-scenarios

### Serviço de Aplicativo do Azure

É uma plataforma do tipo PaaS, ideal para implantar sistemas para várias plataformas, desde aplicações Web, WebAPI, WebSites, etc... Tudo isso podendo ser utilizado nas plataformas .NET, Java, Node.js, Php e Python. Quando falamos em Aplicativos, referimos à recursos de hospedagens. Dentre os benefícios do Serviço de Aplicativo do Azure, segue alguns:

- Suporte a várias linguagens e estruturas
- Otimizaçãõ de DevOps
- Conexões com plataformas SaaS
- Modelos de Aplicativos pré configurados como Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, etc..

Com os Serviços de Aplicativos do Azure você consegue implantar os seguintes tipos de aplicativos:

- Aplicativos / Sites Web
- Aplicativos móveis como hospedagem do backend
- API do tipo RESTful
- Aplicativos Lógicos como Azure Functions

**Segue alguns links para entender melhor como funciona o Azure Service Fabric**

- https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/app-service/
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/app-service-how-works-readme
- https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/app-service/app-service-value-prop-what-is

### Conclusão

Podemos hospedar um simples site com Conteiner Services, Service Fabric ou Serviço de Aplicativo, porem com Conteiner e Service Fabric, exige uma certa configuração de ambiente, já no Serviço de Aplicação do Azure não é necessário nenhum tipo de configuração de ambiente.